# Cannot set a NULL value in Symfony on a manyToOne association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2. I am trying to set a NULL value on a ManyToOne association and I keep getting this error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to WIC\SettlementBundle\Entity\SettlementReport::setSupplierPayment() must be an instance of WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ffss/src/WIC/SupplierBundle/Controller/SupplierPaymentController.php on line 312 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ffss/src/WIC/SettlementBundle/Entity/SettlementReport.php line 342

Here is the association in my settlementReport entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment", inversedBy="supplierReport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplierPayment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $supplierPayment;
```

Here is the getter and setter methods:

```
 /**
 * Set supplierPayment
 *
 * @param \WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment $supplierPayment
 * @return SettlementReport
 */
public function setSupplierPayment(\WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment $supplierPayment)
{
    $this->supplierPayment = $supplierPayment;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get supplierPayment
 *
 * @return \WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment $supplierPayment
 */
public function getSupplierPayment()
{
    return $this->supplierPayment;
}
```

Here is my controller where I am trying to set a NULL value:

```
 $settlementReport = $em->getRepository('WICSettlementBundle:SettlementReport')->find($srId);
 $settlementReport->setSupplierPayment(NULL);
 $em->flush($settlementReport);
```

Why is it giving me that error and how can I set the value to NULL?

Thanks

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Symfony2 - this is all Doctrine2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to allow NULL to be set (which is apparently the case), simply change the signature as follows:

```
public function setSupplierPayment
    (\WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment $supplierPayment = null)
```

Background: PHP forces you to pass an object of the type-casted class, and nothing else; the only exception is the `null` value, if the default parameter value is null, too.

Comment: Omg came back to this after a couple of years (I already upvoted the answer). But this made as little logic that apparently I didn't want to learn it.